# iOS - Matching Interface Colors

Tags: user-interface, ios, colors, uiswitch

Hey all, I'm working on the graphics for an app that uses a mix between custom and stock interface art. For example, the UISliders are customized, and the UISwitches are stock. I know the colors used in my custom art, however, the blue gradient used on a UISwitch continues to elude me. Does anyone know how to reproduce that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sort of hoping for an easy answer, but I just ended up print-screening the UISwitch and using the eyedropper. I can post my color settings if needed.

Comment: I find myself doing this quite often - the Snipping Tool can be quite helpful :)